# Difference between HMACSHA512 constructor and factory

Tags: c#, cryptography

Why does this returns a hash size of 512 bit ...

```
var text = "Hello World";
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512();
hmac.Key = GetRandomBits(512);
hmac.ComputeHash(buffer);

Assert.That(hmac.HashSize, Is.EqualTo(512));
```

... and this a hash size of 160 bit?

```
var text = "Hello World";
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

var hmac = System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512.Create();
hmac.Key = GetRandomBits(512);
hmac.ComputeHash(buffer);

Assert.That(hmac.HashSize, Is.EqualTo(512)); // failure
```

The constructor and the factory are both related to HMACSHA512, so I assumend the same output.

Comment: If you down vote my question, please leave a comment!

Comment: Hi dh_cgn. Can you help me out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087158/hybrid-cryptosystem-implementation-in-net-error-specified-key-is-not-a-valid-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `HMACSHA512.Create()`. You're actually calling `HMAC.Create()` (because the language allows writing calls to static methods off of derived types)

So you're just getting "an HMAC", which seems to be HMACSHA1.

Comment: Is this in this case not a design flaw ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the Create factory method is not doing HMACSHA512 when used in this way.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a6y9t8s(v=vs.110).aspx) breaks it down for us.

> Return Value Type: System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC A new SHA-1
>   instance, unless the default settings have been changed by using the
>    element.

So it looks like the reason they are different in size is because the Create Method is returning a SHA-1 instance instead of the HMACSHA512 instance as you expected.