# Hybrid cryptosystem implementation in .net. Error Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, hybrid, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to implement hybrid cryptosystem as mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem

At the moment I have implemented following algorithm

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParams);
            string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
            string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));
            string symmericKey = "Kamran12";
            txtEncryptedData.Text = EncryptData(txtInputData.Text, symmericKey);
            string encryptedsymmetrickey = EncryptData(symmericKey, publicKey); //error line
            //string decryptsymmetrickey = encryptedsymmetrickey + privateKey;

            //string decrypteddata = encryptedData + decryptsymmetrickey;

        }

        public string EncryptData(string data, string key)
        {
            string encryptedData = null;

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptSrvckey = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(key)
            };
            desCryptSrvckey.IV = desCryptSrvckey.Key;

            using (MemoryStream stmCipherText = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stmCipherText, desCryptSrvckey.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();


                    encryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stmCipherText.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
```

But getting error Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm. at the time of encrypting the symmetric key

Comment: Your `publicKey` is bigger than the allowed 64-bits which are expected for this encryption method. This is why you get the exception.
It's 200 bytes which is 1600 bits.

Comment: That's kind of true, but the fact that the wrong algorithm / key combination is used to "wrap" the DES key using RSA is the underlying error.

Comment: Rolled back to last version. This is a Q/A site, not a debugging website. Do not update your code with (partial) solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to encrypt using the (insecure) DES algorithm with an RSA public key. That's always going to fail, `DESCryptoServiceProvider` doesn't accept RSA keys. You'd need an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` for that.

You may want to consider using a specific library that already implements hybrid cryptography (PGP, CMS or one of the proprietary protocols). The way you are going at it your solution may run in the end, but it will **not** be secure.

Comment: DES as cipher. Tsk.

Comment: Can you suggest correction in current implementation. Can't able to find any thing on github e.t.c regarding hybrid cryptography

Comment: I thought it was obvious, but I've adjusted the answer. Don't stringify your bytes unless strictly required. Strings are nice for human readable text; no need to convert everything to string and back all the time. The DES keys should be encoded to bytes.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Though done lots of development but bit new in cryptography world. Will have a go with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Comment: Beware that one thing is different for the crypto world: the goal is to get it secure rather than to get it working. You can have an implementation that "works" like a charm (most of the time, if you are unlucky) and is insecure. You need to know what you are doing to develop crypto.

Comment: Maarten now i am stucked at the last point. Have able to encrypt data using symmetric key, encrypt and then decrypt symmetric key. Just decryption of data is pending

Comment: Great, so where are you "stucked"?

Comment: At Final step. Encrypted data is not decrypting. getting error the length of data to decrypt is inalid

Comment: Please post a new question with the code included. Do not update this one. And pretty please at least accept and or upvote this answer.

Comment: Ok. Question posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110224/hybrid-cryptography-length-of-the-data-to-decrypt-is-invalid

Comment: My Bad. It was just due to textbox (which i amusing for test purpose) giving me the problem. When saved the data in file after encryption and during decryption i fetch the data via file it worked like a charm. 
Thanks a lot Maarten for the guidance. Now I might check at which point i can use AES as somebody suggested it is better due to it's security