# Hybrid cryptography. Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, hybrid, encryption-asymmetric

I am getting above mentioned error during a hybrid cryptography implementation.

as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem

I am just stucked at the last step

My code is

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);
                string publicKey =lblPublicKey.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
                string privateKey = lblPrivateKey.Text= Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));
                string symmericKey = txtBoxSymmetricKey.Text = "Kamran12";
                txtEncryptedData.Text = EncryptData(txtInputData.Text, symmericKey);
                txtBoxEncryptedSymmetricKey.Text = RSA_Encrypt(symmericKey, publicKey);



                txtBoxDescryptedSymmetricKey.Text = RSA_Decrypt(txtBoxEncryptedSymmetricKey.Text, privateKey);
                txtDecryptedData.Text = DecryptData(txtEncryptedData.Text, txtBoxDescryptedSymmetricKey.Text); //getting error length of the data to decrypt is invalid
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

            }

        }

        public static string RSA_Decrypt(string encryptedText, string privateKey)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));
            var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            byte[] plainBytes = rsaProvider.Decrypt(buffer, false);
            string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            return plainText;
        }

        public static string RSA_Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));
            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaProvider.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }



        public string EncryptData(string data, string key)
        {
            string encryptedData = null;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptSrvckey = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(key)
            };
            desCryptSrvckey.IV = desCryptSrvckey.Key;
            using (MemoryStream stmCipherText = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stmCipherText, desCryptSrvckey.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();


                    encryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stmCipherText.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }

        public string DecryptData(string data, string key)
        {

            byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            string decryptedData = null;
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptSrvckey = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(key)
            };
            desCryptSrvckey.IV = desCryptSrvckey.Key;
            using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedMessageBytes))
            {
                using (
                    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, desCryptSrvckey.CreateDecryptor(),
                        CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        decryptedData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return decryptedData;
        }
```

Comment: I would guess you pass empty string to decryption

Comment: No it is not empty. You can try the code

Comment: Do not use DES for new work , it is no longer secure, use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard), it is no more difficult to use. Do not use the key for the IV, Instead use a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason fro a public/private key pair just use symmetric key encryption such as AES.

Comment: Yes i has some reason. check my two posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060925/encrypting-with-lengthy-string-data-getting-error-bad-length and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087158/hybrid-cryptosystem-implementation-in-net-error-specified-key-is-not-a-valid-s for detail due to which i needed to implement a hybrid  cryptography logic as suggested by lots of guys

Comment: Only Problems Was textbox. I have written the information in a file (which will be the real scenario) and decry pt the information from file and it did work. For the testing purpose i am trying to fill the encrypted data in the textbox which is creating problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare `encryptedData` as a string. This is incorrect.  Your encrypted data is bytes, not a character string.  Attempting to convert raw bytes to UTF-8 text, as in `encryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stmCipherText.ToArray());` will not result in UTF-8 text but give you garbage and possibly lose data.

If you want the output from your encryption to be as text, then take the cyphertext bytes and use `Convert.ToBase64String()` to turn them into a text string.

When decrypting, convert the Base64 string back into bytes and decrypt the bytes.